# Authenticate to Dynamics 365 On premise

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I am trying connect to Dynamics 365 On-premise with the OData client for .net

I tried to authenticate through basic authentication, however this is not working.

```
var c = new Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.System(new Uri("https://mycrm01/crm/api/data/v8.2/"));

c.SendingRequest2 += (o, requestEventArgs) => {
     var creds = username + ":" + password;
     var encodedCreds = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(creds));
     requestEventArgs.RequestMessage.SetHeader("Authentication", "Basic" + encodedCreds);
};

var contacts = c.Contacts.Where(x => x.Firstname=="testuser");
foreach (var contact in contacts)
{

}
```

The error I recieve is: HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied

Can someone help me how this is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general I only use the OData client from JavaScript. When using .NET, I use the SDK libraries that provide authentication and access via the [CrmServiceClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.tooling.connector.crmserviceclient.aspx) class.

To use the OData client from C#, this article outlines the various authentication methods: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt595798.aspx

> Web API authentication patterns
>
> There are three different ways to manage authentication when using the
>   Web API. With JavaScript in web resources
>
> When you use the Web API with JavaScript within HTML web resources,
>   form scripts, or ribbon commands you don’t need to include any code
>   for authentication. In each of these cases the user is already
>   authenticated by the application and authentication is managed by the
>   application. With on-premises deployments
>
> When you use the Web API for on-premises deployments you must include
>   the user’s network credentials. The following example is a C# function
>   that will return an HttpClient configured for a given user’s network
>   credentials: C#

```
private HttpClient getNewHttpClient(string userName,string
password,string domainName, string webAPIBaseAddress) {
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domainName)
 });
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webAPIBaseAddress);
 client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
return client; 
}
```

> With Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online) or internet facing deployments
>
> When you use the Web API for Dynamics 365 (online) or an on-premises
>   Internet-facing deployment (IFD) you must use OAuth as described in
>   Connect to Microsoft Dynamics 365 web services using OAuth.
>
> If you’re creating a single page application (SPA) using JavaScript
>   you can use the adal.js library as described in Use OAuth with
>   Cross-Origin Resource Sharing to connect a Single Page Application to
>   Microsoft Dynamics 365.